# Why the auto binded props yields a warning message at run-time by propTypes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Context**: 
I wrote a simple wrapper for auto binding the props.

**The code**: 
Simply use `create-react-app` to create a new app, and replace `App.js` with the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function Binder ({allState, children}) {
  const child = React.Children.only(children);
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    name: allState.name,
    age: allState.age
  });
}

function People ({name, age}) {
  return(
    <div>
      <p>name: {name}</p>
      <p>age: {age}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'albert',
      age: 99
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Binder allState={this.state}>
          <People />
        </Binder>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`App` is the main entry, `Binder` is a wrapper to bind the `state` to `People`.

**The problem**: 
It all works flawlessly until I add the `propTypes`,

```
People.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  age: PropTypes.number.isRequired
}
```

Even the react dev tools shows that `People` does receive the two needed `prop`, it still print the following warnings:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `name` is marked as required in `People`, but its value is `undefined`.
>       in People (at App.js:38)
>       in App (at index.js:7)
>
> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `age` is marked as required in `People`, but its value is `undefined`.
>       in People (at App.js:38)
>       in App (at index.js:7)

**How to overcome this?**: 
I found the only way for overcoming this, is either remove that `isRequired`, and assign the default prop. Or simply remove the `PropTypes`.

**Why?**: 
Feel not right.

Am I doing something when doing the auto binding?

Why it prints the warning while it does receive the value, seems it doesn't receive the value when initializing?

What is the best way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is raised because you're instantiating `<People>` in `App.render()` even before `Binder` has the opportunity to clone the element.

A possible solution would be to pass the *type* of component (class/function), instead of an instance, and let `Binder` instantiate.

```
const { child } = this.props;
return React.createElement(child, {
  name: allState.name,
  age: allState.age
});
```

or:

```
const { child: Child } = this.props;
return (<Child name={allState.name} age={allState.age} />);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, reasonable, proved my guess. But this approach will not work well if I have multiple children, right? Anyway for solve that? set `defaultProps`?

Comment: Yes, `defaultProps` will prevent the warning